# Redirect from CDN to Primary website on direct access of CDN domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, cdn

I'm not quite sure how to prevent google from indexing my CDN domain in mix with my Primary domain name. I would like to redirect to Primary domain via .htaccess on dirrect access to CDN domain.

Facts:

1. Both domains point to the same place in file sistem.
2. Both share same robots.txt
3. CDN domain: cdn.example.com
4. Primary domain: example.com

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't entirely understand what your question is. Can you make an example of what needs to be redirected how?

Comment: wouldn't having the `same robots.txt` on both domains be the issue? shouldn't you have a different one for your CDN, to properly prevent Google-Bot from indexing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following rewrite rules will redirect any request to cdn.example.com to example.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} =cdn.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: He wants to go the other direction -- from the CDN to his primary domain.

Comment: Yes, that's what this is doing :-)

Comment: Thanks, working like i wanted it. Only 1 typo there "RewrriteRule" -> "RewriteRule".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any CDN's explicitly supporting this type of redirect, but my guess is that many of them do.

If your CDN does not, then the best you can do is put an index.html file there with a redirect header -- and this isn't a bad solution at all.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://primarydomain.com/" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Search engines will even [consider this a proper 301](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/google-and-yahoo-treat-undelayed-meta-refresh-as-301-redirect/).